# Randomly generating winners

Tags: python, random

I am having trouble figuring out why this works the way it does.

What I have done so far is generate 5 groups with random amount of numbers 1-20. For example group 1 could have 1,16, 19; group 2 could have 2,6,10, 11, 15; so on and so forth. What I am trying to do is pick a winner by generating a random number 1-20, then I want to get rid of the winning group of numbers and pick another random number for 2nd place.

Everything is working well except if group 5 wins, then the numbers aren't being deleted from the list. I am a beginner in python so I am trying to understand this. Here is the snippet of code:

```
Winners_List = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)

Winning_Number = random.sample(Winners_List, 1)

Winning_Horse = []


for i in Winning_Number:
    if i in Horse1:
        Winning_Horse = Horse1
    elif i in Horse2:
        Winning_Horse = Horse2
    elif i in Horse3:
        Winning_Horse = Horse3
    elif i in Horse4:
        Winning_Horse = Horse4
    else:
        Winning_Horse = Horse5

Second_Place_List = [i for i in Winners_List if i not in Winning_Horse]
```

`Second_Place_List` is generating the correct list except when `Winning_Horse` = `Horse5`.

Any reason why?

Comment: Why not provide a [mcve]? The code snippet that you have given depends on variables that you have defined elsewhere.

Comment: Why don't you say `elif i in Horse5:`?

Comment: What seems surprising in your code is the fact that you do not check if i is in the group Horses5. The issue may be that the i that is picked does not exists in Horses5 but since i does not exists in any other group, Horses5 is selected as the winner group. This would result in i appearing in the Second_Place_List

Comment: Why go through all this when you could just shuffle the list of horses and pick the first two as winner and 2nd place?  `horses = [1,2,3,4,5]; random.shuffle(horses); winners = horses[:2]`

Comment: Or avoid the shuffle by going straight to `random.sample(horses, 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code, the winning number is a list with just one value, so, a for loop isn't the better approach.

My suggestion:

```
winners_list = (
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
  7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
  12, 13, 14, 15,
  16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
)
arrival_order = random.sample(winners_list, len(winners_list))
winner = arrival_order[0]
second_place_list = arrival_order[1:]
```

arrival_order will receive a list with random values from winners list like this:

> [20, 12, 3, 17, 18, 13, 1, 19, 9, 8, 10, 16, 6, 2, 11, 5, 15, 4, 14,
>   7]

Variable values:

winner: 20

second_place_list : [12, 3, 17, 18, 13, 1, 19, 9, 8, 10, 16, 6, 2, 11, 5, 15, 4, 14, 7]

Answer (score 0):

## Does this help?

```
Winners_List = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

Winning_Number = random.sample(Winners_List, 1)

for i in Winning_Number:
    if i in Horse1:
        Winning_Horse = Horse1
    elif i in Horse2:
        Winning_Horse = Horse2
    elif i in Horse3:
        Winning_Horse = Horse3
    elif i in Horse4:
        Winning_Horse = Horse4
    else:
        Winning_Horse = Horse5
        
# I remove the Winning_Number from the Winners_List
Winners_List.pop(Winners_List.index(Winning_Number))
# Now Winners_List is the Second_Place_List
```